# How to autowire when constructor arguments are specified at runtime?

Tags: spring-boot, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, autowired

I have a domain class that i want to inject into the facade of its module, this class have constructor arguments that are specified at runtime. The definition of this class is as shown below:

```
@Component("area")
@Scope("prototype")
public class GeographicalCircleArea {
    private Location center;
    private double radius;

    private final IShopsProviderAdapter shopsProviderAdapter;

    @Autowired
    GeographicalCircleArea(double centerLatitude, double centerLongitude, double radiusInKm, IShopsProviderAdapter shopsProviderAdapter) {
        this.center = makeCenter(centerLatitude, centerLongitude);
        this.radius = radiusInKm;
        this.shopsProviderAdapter = shopsProviderAdapter;
    }

    List<Shop> getShopsWithin() {
        return shopsProviderAdapter.findShopsWithin(this);
    }

    public Location getCenter() {
        return center;
    }

    public double getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }

    private Location makeCenter(double latitude, double longitude) {
        return new Location(latitude, longitude);
    }
}
```

The facade where I want to inject the precedent bean is:

```
@Service
public class GeolocationInformationSystem {

    @Autowired
    private GeographicalCircleArea area;

    public List<Shop> searchForNearbyShops(double centerLatitude, double centerLongitude, double radiusInKm) {
        return area.getShopsWithin();
    }
}
```

which gets the arguments to instantiate GeographicalCircleArea at runtime.
How to correctly apply the autowiring?

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation they make it clear :

> For each bean, its dependencies are expressed in the form of properties, constructor arguments, or arguments to the static-factory method if you are using that instead of a normal constructor. **These dependencies are provided to the bean, when the bean is actually created.**

That mean your application crash before running any code in runtime because of :

```
 @Autowired
private GeographicalCircleArea area;
```

Simple reason you can't inject unknown values because they are unknown during container initialization process and bean creation step,

How to solve that: changing your implementation by changing the constructor

```
@Autowired
GeographicalCircleArea(IShopsProviderAdapter shopsProviderAdapter) {

    this.shopsProviderAdapter = shopsProviderAdapter;
}
```

and change

```
 List<Shop> getShopsWithin() {
    return shopsProviderAdapter.findShopsWithin(this);
}
```

to take those arguments :

```
List<Shop> getShopsWithin(double centerLatitude, double centerLongitude, 
        double radiusInKm) {
    this.center = makeCenter(centerLatitude, centerLongitude);
    this.radius = radiusInKm;
    return shopsProviderAdapter.findShopsWithin(this);
}
```

Comment: This can work that way. But it will make the getShopsWithin low cohesive, means it has to deal now with more than it should be: the initialization of the area and the provision of the list of shops.

Comment: This is true, however this initialization must be done somewhere but not in the constructor, in daily code i use to implement this pattern : object.setProp1(value).executeMethod() for both initialization and calling a method on an object,